# Triage how to flag questions asking how to make things?

Tags: discussion, triage, needs-more-focus

In Triage I've encountered questions that is a good fit for VLQ but since that's not an option in Triage flags, how can I flag questions that are VLQ?

Examples are those questions asking how to do xxx without stating any code attempt or on worse occasions not even stating the language they want to use.

I can't flag as unclear what you're asking since they made that clear but the lack of attempt(code) is a violation of how to ask in SO.

Or is it a fit for opinion based as different people has a different approach in creating a script.

Comment: Unsalvageable > should be closed... > too broad?

Comment: Isn't that reserved for questions that cover multiple topics at once? i.e how to do this with PHP and process result in JAVA while waiting for a PERL response?

Comment: No, that's reserved for questions that require more effort to answer than they're worth.

Comment: Ohh my take away on that is the limit to a specific topic on the too broad description. Maybe they should update it to include this scenario as well as it didn't become clear to me until you pointed it out.

Comment: Asking how to do stuff, even without providing a code attempt, is not inherently off-topic.

Comment: NOTE: Only debugging questions *require* code, a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (homework requires an attempt). No other question type *requires* code, or an attempt. Having code often helps to narrow and clarify a question. Thus, many questions without code are "too broad" and/or "unclear", but *just* the lack of code doesn't make them off-topic (again, except debugging, but a MCVE *could* exist without code). So, in other words, evaluate the question fully; don't respond to *just* the lack of code with a knee-jerk reaction of voting/flagging as off-topic.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

TL;DR - Flag(Unsalvageable) it for **closure**.

In Triage you have

- **Looks OK** - Don't pick this here obviously
- **Requires Editing** - Unless **YOU** think that **YOU** could edit this question into shape (not the asker), don't pick this
- **Unsalvageable** - We have a winner!

**Unsalvageable** is really a disguised **flag** link. It opens the same dialogue, minus the VLQ option (which isn't the greatest anyways). Honestly, VLQ just makes other people in another queue pick from the remaining options. If the question is VLQ, you need to pick a closure reason. [3x Unsalvageable](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20011133) is the only way to get it out of the Triage queue without throwing it into the badly named "Help & Improvement" queue (where frustrated users will either close it or VLQ flag it back into Triage).

Comment: I'll be honest here I always used this `Requires Editing` thinking that the OP is the one who will update the question. Thank you for the information. :)

Answer (score 10):

You appear to not understand what the VLQ flag is.  The VLQ flag is saying, "this question should go into Triage so that someone else can flag the question for some reason".  Obviously since you're *in* Triage, it makes no sense to allow you to flag the question to go into Triage.  As a result, the flag is basically pointless.  It's just a flag reason that says you want someone else to pick a more specific flag reason for you.  (And if you can't figure out what other reason should be used, you really shouldn't be flagging it at all.)

Save them the effort and just flag it yourself for whatever more specific reason you feel is appropriate.  If you don't feel *any* of the other flag reasons are appropriate, then *don't flag the question as VLQ*, because, at best, the Triage users that see it will just be forced to dismiss your flag.

As for the type of question you're describing, it would depend on the specifics, but a lot of those types of questions will be Too Broad, many will also be Unclear.  If the specific question doesn't merit closure for any reason, but you don't think it's a helpful question, then *downvote it*.  That (not the VLQ flag) is the appropriate means of indicating that you don't think a question is a quality question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out to me. I didn't know that VLQ just means move this to triage. I'll keep this all in mind. :)

Comment: Well, the only path that VLQ flagging provides that other flags don't is going "Triage" ➞ "Help & Improvement" (to be edited by someone else), so a VLQ flag is valid if you feel that some other user, not the OP, could edit the question into shape, but you can't. However, I agree that doing so is really just putting a work off onto other people when you could edit it yourself. OTOH, the edits that are needed might not be easy for a user w/o edit privileges to get approved, so a VLQ flag might be a viable option.